# Add months to days using joda-time

Tags: java, jodatime

I need to create a method that takes a number of days and a number of months, add the two, and then returns the resulting number of days.

```
public int addMonthsToDays(int months, int days);//interface
```

I think of using joda DateTime, but there is no method for getting the total days. Here is an example implementation:

```
public int addMonthsToDays(int months, int days){
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().plusDays(days).plusMonths(months);
  return // what do I return?
}
```

**Additional Note**

I know some people will misread the above and come out with a  number of questions, so in anticipation:

- I want the number of days from today, not from 1 jan 1970
- I don't have to use DateTime, the implementation is just what I have tried.
- The goal is to implement the interface `public int addMonthsToDays(int months, int days)` and return the new number of days from today.
- I am happy to answer additional questions

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.

    `public int addMonthsToDays(int months, int days){
        DateTime dateTime = new DateTime().plusDays(days).plusMonths(months);
        return Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(), dateTime).getDays();
    }`

Comment: I must wait 8 hours before posting my answer as reply

Comment: I hope you have also thought about the right order of calculation steps you need, since plusDays().plusMonths() is sometimes not equal to plusMonths().plusDays(). And yes, also the referencing date for plusMonths() is important.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I am not aware of that. Do you have references discussing this? Thanks!

Comment: A month has no fixed length of days hence you need a reference date to start with and so to define result of addition/conversion from months to days, here you seem to use current date. And about the order, just consider [2013-06-30].plus(P1M1D)=[2013-07-31] vs. [2013-06-30].plus(P1D1M)=[2013-08-01].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem is that you are working with dates, but actually want days. What you can do is make a new DateTime for today, and a different one with your added days/months, and then just calculate the difference in days.

in joda-time speak:

```
Days.between(startDate, endDate);
```

complete (untested) example would look like

```
public int addMonthsToDays(int months, int days){
  DateTime startDate = new DateTime();
  DateTime endDate = new DateTime().plusDays(days).plusMonths(months);
  return Days.between(startDate,endDate);
}
```

Comment: yep. See my comments above. I figured it out. But thanks all the same. ( I have to wait 9 minutes before accepting your answer). in the mean time: +1

Comment: actually I apparently don't have enough reputation to up-vote. so in 9 mintues.  thanks.